# Найти в строке слова с цифрами

Tags: pascal, алгоритм

Как найти в определенном предложении всё слова, где присутствуют цифры.
То есть в итоге вывести количество таких слов.
Делал вот так но что то не работает

```
Function num_count(s:string):integer;
Var i,num:integer;
n:0..9;
word:string;
begin
num:=0;
word:='';
for i:=1 to Length(S) do //просматриваем всю строку
begin
if(S[i]=' ') then    //если пробел то новое слово
  word:=''
else
begin
  //если находим цифру то прибавляем счетчик
if Pos(inttostr(n),word)<>0 then
num:=num+1;
word:=word+S[i];
Continue;
end;

Result:= num;
end;end;
```

Comment: Я поправил свой код, попробуйте, может прокатит. Нужно заменить им цикл For.

Comment: Всё, поправил и протестил - у меня пашет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант выше при пробелах подряд в середине и конце строки ошибается

А так же использует долгие функции

Вот приемлимый код по скорости и объему кода

```
function num_count(s:string):integer;
var
  i,num,len:integer;

begin
  num:=0;
  i:=1;
  len:=length(s);

   while (i<=len) do
        if (s[i] in ['0'..'9'] )
         then
            begin
            inc(num);
            while ( (s[i] <> ' ') and (i<=len) ) do inc(i);
            end
         else inc(i);

  result:= num;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Поправил.

```
    Function num_count(s:string):integer;
    Var
      i,num:integer;
    begin

      num:=0;

      i:=1;

     While (S[Length(S)]=' ') Do // удаляю пробелы в конце
       Delete(S, Length(S), 1);

// Вместо предыдущего цикла в Delphi можно использовать S:=Trim(S);

        While (i<=Length(S)) Do
          Begin
            If (S[i]=' ') Then
              Begin
                Repeat // теперь не ошибётся
                  delete(S, 1, 1);
                Until (S[1]<>' ');
                i:=1;
              End;

            if (S[i] In ['0'..'9']) then
              Begin
                num:=num+1;
                If (Pos(' ', S)=0) Then
                  Break // можно написать так
                  {Begin // или так
                    Result:= num;
                    Exit;
                  End}
                Else
                  delete(S, 1, Pos(' ', S));
                i:=1;
              End
            Else
              Inc(i);
          End;

      Result:= num;
    end;
```

Теперь мой вариант не ошибается, если пробелов в центр строки натыкать, хотя достаточно велик по объёму кода (оптимизацией я тут не занимался - написал то, что первое в голову пришло).

Comment: выдает ошибку на условии :
Operator not applicable to this operand type

Comment: Все равно никак